# Number of coin flip problem

Tags: probability

What's the expected number of times that I need to toss an unbiased coin until I've seen heads four times?

I worked out the answer to be 30 but it was a wrong answer.

However, it seems that I am missing something.

EDIT: So my previous post relates to four tosses in a row. So i removed it.

Comment: Seen heads $4$ times is very different from seen heads $4$ times in a row. Which one do you intend?

Comment: You don't want them *in a row*, you just want them, period: in any order, possibly with tails in between.

Comment: Do you want to see four heads total or four consecutive

Comment: Not in a row. four total

Comment: If you want more than just the expectation, you may want to look at the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution): the number you are considering is basically $X+4$, where $X\sim NB(4,1/2)$. (This also gives you the expectation, but may be overkill.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each heads has probability $p=\frac12$ and thus takes an expected number $\frac1p=2$ of tosses. By linearity of expectation, four of them take four times as long, i.e. $8$ tosses.